# На каком языке программирования создана Intellij IDEA и PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, ide

На каком языке программирования создана Intellij IDEA и PyCharm?

P.S. Вопрос задаю чисто из интереса.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA - Java, PyCharm - Java и Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на Яве. Это можно заметить по параметрам запуска программы.

Comment: ну там говорят ещё котлин есть.

Comment: Котлин компилируется в Яву - так что возможно, но основа IDEA делалась до изобретения котлина.

Comment: насколько я знаю, котлин не транспилел, а "компилятор" в байт код jvm (но оно умеет и в javascript/llvm). Но то, что IDEA появилась раньше - никто не спорит

Answer (score 0):

Они написаны на джаве, по крайней мере, так пишут сами разработчики на своём сайте (я о Пайчарм).

Comment: Спасибо большое!